# Functions with dynamic parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use this function to retrieve an array from a web service.

```
button.onclick = function(item) {
            var nonReplying = new Array(getNoreply(item)); 
            console.log(nonReplying);
            setTimeout(unInviteUsers(item, nonReplying), 2500);
        }.bind(button, EventsArray[i][1]);
```

Then the function

```
    function unInviteUsers(event,nonReplying)
{

      //remember to parseInt() the first param, Event ID as well 
      for(var i = 0; i <= nonReplying.length; i++)  
        {
            unInvite(event,parseInt(nonReplying[0][i].replace('"','').replace('"','')),AccessToken);
        } 
}
```

calls this function

```
    function unInvite(event, user)
{   

    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+event+'/invited/'+user+'?access_token='+AccessToken,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) 
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
    });
}
```

But when button.onclick gets triggered some how the array nonReplying is not passed and unInviteUsers() returns

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'nonReplyingArray[0][i].replace')

And by the way, how do I properly force a function to wait until an other function is fully finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `nonReplying` actually a two-dimensional array?

Also, aside from the `undefined` error,

```
setTimeout(unInviteUsers(item, nonReplying), 2500);
```

will not do what you want. I believe you want that unInviteUsers to fire after 2.5 seconds. The first parameter of `setTimeout` needs to be a reference to a function. Unless `unInviteUsers` returns an anonymous function itself, this won't do the trick, but this might:

```
setTimeout(function() { unInviteUsers(item, nonReplying) }, 2500);
```

Comment: Yes it's a two-dim. array

Comment: Ah, another thing: Your for loop's abort condition is `<=` instead of `<` (index 0-based vs. length) which might be an issue. :)

Comment: Hmh I've tried this before, but actually setting < instead of <= does not reach every element in the array... But thank you for the suggestion. Btw how would you force unInviteUsers() to wait for getNoreply(item) to finish... I know that Javascript will not wait for a function to finish and it will execute the other immediately